# maximum flow algorithm to find a maximum cardinality matching in a bipartite graph.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, integer-programming, network-flow

How could I show how a maximum flow problem can be used to find a maximum cardinality matching in a bipartite graph?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Introduce a source node with arcs to the left node set and a sink node with arcs from the right node set, and maximize the flow from source to sink.